# May the words "Creation" and "Creativity" be used in the same way?

Tags: meaning

Consider a soccer player in the penalty box area of the pitch. He is extraordinarily creative in his skills in this area. It may be said that his "Creativity" is second to none, but may the word "Creation" be used instead? To wit: the striker Colyn Matthews' "Creation" in the penalty area is second to none. There is a current football commentator in England named Ian Joy and "Creation" is his favorite descriptor when a player shows imagination when scoring a goal. I believe that he is erring in his usage of "Creation". Any thoughtful opinions would be welcome. Thanks, Willard Goode, FL, USA.

Comment: Have you got an example of Ian Joy saying this?  As a British English speaker I've never heard "creation" used that way in conversations about footballing creativity - it sounds wrong to me too! If he'd  sat down and dug a sandcastle in the penalty box, *that*  item could be referred to as "his creation".... Or  maybe when referring to an object in the general sense - e.g. "his creation *of passing manoeuvres* is excellent" or "creation *of chances*".

Answer (score 7):

**Creation** is the act of giving rise to something that has hitherto not been there. *Creative* [originally had the meaning](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=creative&allowed_in_frame=0) of *having the quality of creating*, but later transformed in usage to mean *imaginative*. And to answer your question, no, *creation* does not mean *the quality of being imaginative* and cannot stand in for *creativity*.